# Use GKE beta features with GCP Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to create GKE REGION cluster (beta feature) with GCP deployment manager.
But I got error. Is there any way to use GKE beta features (include region cluster) with deployment manager?

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in             
Operation [operation-1525054837836-56b077fdf48e0-a571296c-604523fb]: 
errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/test-cluster1/resources/source-cluster
  message: '{"ResourceType":"container.v1.cluster","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"v1 API cannot be used to access GKE regional clusters. See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/api-organization#beta for more information.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project_id/zones/us-central1/clusters","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

In the error message, link of gcp help.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/api-organization#beta

Configured as described there but error still appears.

My deployment manager yaml file looks like,

```
resources:
- name: source-cluster
type: container.v1.cluster
properties:
  zone: us-central1
  cluster:
    name: source
    initialNodeCount: 3
```

Yet, zonal cluster is completely work. So I think it's related to usage of container v1beta api in deployment-manager commands.

```
resources:
- name: source-cluster
type: container.v1.cluster
properties:
  zone: us-central1-b
  cluster:
    name: source
    initialNodeCount: 3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are receiving appears to be related to the fact that you are attempting to use a beta feature but you are specifying a Deployment Manager resource as using API v1 (i.e. container.v1.cluster). This means there's inconstancy between the beta resource you are trying to create and the specified resource.

I've had a look into this and discovered that the ability to add regional clusters via Deployment Manager is a very recent addition to Google Cloud Platform as detailed in this [public feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/72372261) which has only recently been implemented.

It seems you would need to specify the API type as 'gcp-types/container-v1beta1:projects.locations.clusters' for this to work, and rather than using the 'zone' or 'region' key in the YAML, you would instead use a parent property that includes locations.

So your YAML would look something like this (replace PROJECT_ID with your own).

```
resources:
- type:  gcp-types/container-v1beta1:projects.locations.clusters
  name: source-cluster
  properties:
   parent: projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1
   cluster:
     name: source
     initialNodeCount: 3
```